# List Employee Certifications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, database, access

My company has about 30 employees and I'm trying to create an easily-accessible method for everyone to view each other's certifications (type, cert #, exp. date, etc.) but I'm not really sure what the best method to tackle this would be.

Any suggestions?

Dustin

Comment: A custom list will work. Sounds like MS access is your datasource for this? Or will you manually manage the data in SharePoint?

Comment: I'd like to manage the data in SharePoint so I don't have to keep going back to access for updates. It's going to be a volatile list (as new employees are hired, expiration dates change, new certifications are earned, etc.) I just want it complete enough to store all the applicable data while being user-friendly and easy on the eyes so people don't have to be a database wizard to acquire the information needed.

Comment: with Lists of SharePoint? SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom list in SharePoint with following fields

1. Employee Name - Person field which pulls Employee name from User Profile (which can be tied to Active Directory)
2. Type of Certification - Choice Field (You can fill in all available certifications)
3. Certification # - Single line of text
4. Expiry Date - Date field

If your employee data is not available in User Profiles, then you can create another list to store the employee information. And add a lookup field to populate the employees.

Comment: You could also create a view, which would group the certificates by the person.